# Sklearn: feature extraction type error

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror, feature-extraction

As a beginner in programming, I have some problems with the categorization of text via a machine learning experiment with Scikit learn. I use 10-fold cross validation so there is no division in train and test data.

My problem starts in the feature extraction module. This is the code with the error:

```
vec = DictVectorizer() 
X = vec.fit_transform(instances).toarray()
```

The last line gives the following error:

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'

Instances is a list of feature vector dictionaries,with a dictionary per document. An example of the beginning of the instances list (you can see a part of the dictionary for the first document).

[image: instances] Some features are a dictionary nested in the feature vector dictionary. I don't know how to make it unnested, but maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Yes the nested dictionaries are the problem. You must find a way to either encode them to specific values or unwrap them and make them be in the same level as the other key-values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,the problem is with your nested dictionary feature vector. Split them and make them independent features.